# Задачка по подсчету количеству бревен

Tags: python

Здравствуйте, ищу разрешение задачки по подсчету количества
бревен в рядах в Python. В качестве `input` вводится число рядов, в которых хранятся брёвна.

Условием является то, что в самом верхнем ряду лежит одно бревно и в каждом следующем ряду количество брёвен увеличивается на 1. Например: если число рядов 6, то количество бревен должно быть `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21`.

Идея кода в том, чтобы взять промежуток чисел от 1го до последнего в `число_рядов` и прибавлять к каждому из них по одному. Программа выдает ошибку

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

```
число_рядов = int(input ("Введите число рядов: "))
i = 0
число_бревен= число_рядов([1,-1]+1)
while i<число_бревен:
    число_бревен= число_рядов([1,-1]+1)
    i=i+1
    print (int( число_бревен))
```

Comment: Я перечитал код десять раз, но так и не смог понять — какой результат вы ожидаете от выражения `число_рядов([1,-1]+1)` и почему?

Comment: в выражение число_рядов я хочу посчитать общее число брёвен последствием взятия количества всех рядов с первого до последнего и прибавления к ним цифры 1. То есть если число рядов 4, то должно выйти (0+1)+(1+1)+(2+1)+(3+1)=12, возможно выражения написано неправильно (пока только новичок в python)

Comment: Как всё это связано с выражением `число_рядов([1,-1]+1)` я всё ещё не могу понять

Answer (score 6):

```
n = int(input ())
print (n * (n+1)/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input ("Введите число рядов: "))
result= 0
for i in xrange(n+1): 
   result+=i
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 1
число_бревен = 0
while i <= число_рядов:
     число_бревен += i
     i += 1
print(число_бревен)
```

Comment: Тогда уж `for i in range(число_рядов)`, это более python-way, чем `while` со счетчиком.